# SpriteKit: property for disabling taps and touches?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

`userInteractionEnabled` seems to only disable touches? What if we need to ignore taps and touches? Is there a property similar to userInteractionEnabled that also causes taps to get ignored? This is for Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`beginIgnoringInteractionEvents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginIgnoringInteractionEvents) from `UIApplication.sharedApplication`:

```
//Start ignoring
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

To end the ignoring, you can simply use the [`endIgnoringInteractionEvents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/endIgnoringInteractionEvents)

```
//End Ignoring
UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

Comment: Thanks, can't accept answer for 10 min. Could I email you something? Couldn't find your contact info from the website ...